# Slim Route not redirecting the URL

Tags: php, rest, slim

I have the below code in index.php.
When I access localhost it prints "Hello Slim World"
but when I type localhost/help it does not print "Help Me".

Apache try to look for help page which seems to be obvious

[Wed Jan 21 18:20:04 2015] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /var/www/html/help
[Wed Jan 21 18:21:18 2015] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /var/www/html/help

Please help to figure it out how to help route working. i.e when I type localhost/help it should show "Help me" on the browser. I guess I am making some obvious mistake.

```
  <?php
require "Slim/Slim.php";

use Slim\Slim;
// create new Slim instance
Slim::registerAutoloader();



$app = new Slim();

// add new Route
$app->get("/", function () {
    echo "<h1>Hello Slim World</h1>";
});


$app->get("/help", function () {
    echo "<h1>Help Me</h1>";
});

// run the Slim app
$app->run();
```

Comment: do you have the .htaccess file setup? And your site needs AllowOverride All  in your apache config for that directory.

Comment: thanks this is wat I ws missing